# Why won't my UIView load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I modified an existing project's application delegate to default to a standard application delegate and made it add my custom view controller's view to the scene once it launched:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    SplashScreenController *controller = [[SplashScreenController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:controller.view];
    return YES;
}
```

What I don't understand is, why isn't my view showing? The screen is always perma-black after loading, because for sure I can see that the view did in fact load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"View did load.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I did not allocate the window in the view controller, nor did I make the window key and visible. The code should have been as follows in the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    SplashScreenController *controller = [[SplashScreenController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:controller.view];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: in today's iOS, you don't add the viewcontrollers view to the window! You really wanna use the [self.window setRootViewController:controller] method - everything leads to a world of pain if you ever use UIKit again!

Comment: @LordT Oh yeah, like what?

Comment: Pushing a view doesn't necessarily work anymore or might not work anymore in the next version of the OS, the rootViewController getter doesn't work, modally showing a view might fail, etc

Comment: @LordT Thanks. I noticed some strange behavior when I did not use setRootViewController, like rotating the hardware device made the view look strange, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do, but it looks like you mean to be setting your window's root view controller. Try this:

```
SplashScreenController *controller = [[SplashScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"theNibName" bundle:nil];            
[self.window setRootViewController:controller];
```

Comment: I mean, I changed the logic of the default Cocos2D application delegate to a normal iOS application delegate, and am trying to load a simple view onto the screen. Unfortunately, setting the root view controller on my application delegate's window still seems to show a black window :(

Comment: @Alexandru Of course it does. You're just alloc/initing a blank instance of the view controller. If you want to utilize what you've made in your xib, you need to use initWithNib: see the new code in my post.

Comment: Even with the Nib name being "SplashScreenController" or "SplashScreenController.xib", it still shows up black.

Comment: I figured it out, will post the answer shortly. There were a few issues but not the ones you mentioned. I appreciate the help, +1 all around for contributing! Thank you!